# Kotlin / Метод, который принимает функцию фильтрации элементов и возвращает новый объект очереди с отфильтрованными элементами

Tags: kotlin, методы, filter, лямбда-выражение

Есть первичный код:

```
class Queue<T> (list:MutableList<T>) {
    private var items: MutableList<T> = list
    fun isEmpty(): Boolean = items.isEmpty()
    override fun toString() = items.toString()
    fun enqueue(item: T) {
        items.add(item)
    }
    fun dequeue(): T? {
        return items.removeFirstOrNull()
    }
}
```

И мне нужно как-то добавить метод, который принимает функцию фильтрации элементов и возвращает новый объект очереди с отфильтрованными элементами, а потом вызвать функцию filter с использованием лямбда-выражения и ссылки на функцию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Queue<T> (list:MutableList<T>) {
    private var items: MutableList<T> = list
    fun isEmpty(): Boolean = items.isEmpty()
    override fun toString() = items.toString()
    fun enqueue(item: T) {
        items.add(item)
    }
    fun dequeue(): T? {
        return items.removeFirstOrNull()
    }
    
    // Создаем функцию фильтрации
    // Так как функция не меняет существующий объект очереди, 
    // а копирует его с применением фильтрации,будет более правильно
    // назвать ее filtered (отфильтрованный)
    // вместо filter (отфильтровать)
    fun filtered(condition: (T) -> Boolean): Queue {
        // Пояснения по параметру condition
        // тип (T) -> Boolean означает
        // Функция, принимающая на вход объекты типа T
        // и возвращающая объекты типа Boolean
        // В данном случае в очереди останутся те объекты, для 
        // которых condition вернет true

        // фильтруем список используя стандартный метод
        val filteredList = items.filter(condition)
        // создаем новую очередь
        val filteredQueue = Queue(filteredList)
        // возвращаем результат
        return filteredQueue
    }
}
```

Абстрактный Пример вызова:

```
    // Заметим, что эта функция принимает на вход тип T
    // и возвращает Boolean
    // точно как требуется для параметра condition
    fun filterCondition(item: T): Boolean {
        // здесь ваш код определения, должен ли элемент остаться
        // Если должен остаться, то вернуть true
        // Если элемент при фильтрации необходимо удалить - вернуть false

        return true // В таком случае останутся все элементы
    }

    val queue = ... // Создали какую-то очередь

    // Вызов через лямбда-выражение
    val filteredQueueLambda = queue.filter{ filterCondition(it) }

    // Вызов через ссылку на функцию
    val filteredQueueLink = queue.filter(::filterCondition)
```

Конкретный пример вызова:

```
    fun filterLessThen3(item: Int): Boolean {
        return (item < 3)
    }

    val queue = Queue(listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

    // В обоих случаях в очереди должны остаться значения 1, 2
    val filteredQueueLambda = queue.filter{ filterLessThen3(it) }
    val filteredQueueLink = queue.filter(::filterLessThen3)
```